# Why am I getting 2 duplicate outputs after while loop is finished?

Tags: java

This is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String user;
        String pass;
        String newPass;
        String question = "What is your Pass Word? ";
        int newPassLength;
        Scanner userPass = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            do {
                System.out.print("Please Enter your Pass word: ");
                pass = userPass.next();
                newPass = pass;
                newPassLength = newPass.length();

                if (newPassLength >= 3) {
                    System.out.println("This PassWord works.");
                }
                if (newPassLength <= 2) {
                    System.out.println("This PassWord doesn't Work.");
                }
            }
            while (newPassLength <= 2);

            Scanner userPassWord = new Scanner(System.in);

            int one = 1;
            int subtract = 4;
            do {
                System.out.print(question);
                user = userPassWord.next();
                if (user.equals(pass)) {
                    System.out.println("Pass Word is correct you may move on.");
                    break;
                } else {
                    subtract = subtract - one;
                    if(subtract >= 0) {
                        System.out.println("PassWord is wrong. You have " + subtract + " more trys.");
                    }
                }

                if (subtract == 0) {
                    System.out.println("You have no more trys left. Would you like to reset your PassWord?(Y/N)");
                }
                if (user.equals("Y") || user.equals("y")) {
                    System.out.println("You May reset your Password.");
                    main(args);
                    break;
                } else if(user.equals("No") || user.equals("no")) {
                    System.out.println("You do not get anymore trys. The Program will exit.");
                    System.exit(1);
                } else if(subtract <= -1) {
                    System.out.println("You need to answer the question.(Y/N)");
                }
            }
            while(true);
        }
        while(user == pass);

        System.out.println("You may now enter the program.");
    }
}
```

This is my output.

Please Enter your Pass word: true

This PassWord works.

What is your Pass Word? tr

PassWord is wrong. You have 3 more trys.

What is your Pass Word? tr

PassWord is wrong. You have 2 more trys.

What is your Pass Word? tr

PassWord is wrong. You have 1 more trys.

What is your Pass Word? tr

PassWord is wrong. You have 0 more trys.

You have no more trys left. Would you like to reset your PassWord?(Y/N)

What is your Pass Word? y

You May reset your Password.

Please Enter your Pass word: tr

This PassWord doesn't Work.

Please Enter your Pass word: tre

This PassWord works.

What is your Pass Word? tre

Pass Word is correct you may move on.

You may now enter the program.

You may now enter the program.

Process finished with exit code 0

Why at the end am I getting "You may now enter the program." Two times. I should only get it once and I don't think it is looping 2 times after the while loops are done but it looks like it is and I am not sure anyone have any ideas of what is wrong with my program or if I am missing something?

Comment: Not reproducible, it will output only once.

Comment: I tested your code and "You may now enter the program." is only output once for me. It is likely related to the environment you are running your code in rather than the code itself.

Comment: `user == pass` is not how to compare Strings in java

Comment: Something might be wrong when you called main() and the break in the reset password part. Since without resetting the password only output once, and resetting the password twice output three times.

Comment: @enzo  It's reproducible, you need to trigger ```reset password```.

Comment: @sprinter  It's reproducible, you need to trigger ```reset password```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug only occurs when the logic to `reset a password` is triggered.

When this `recursive main` execution is finished, break is executed, and `"You may now enter the program."` is printed again.

```
if (user.equals("Y") || user.equals("y")) {
    System.out.println("You May reset your Password.");
    main(args);
    break;
}
```

The easiest way to do this is to replace `break` with `return`.

I tried not to break the original code and fixed some of the original bugs:

```
public class SO_69983033 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean success = new SO_69983033().passwordSetAndCheck();
        if (success) {
            System.out.println("You may now enter the program.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The Program will exit.");
        }
    }

    public boolean passwordSetAndCheck() {
        String user;
        String question = "What is your Pass Word? ";
        String newPass = setNewPassword();
        Scanner userPassWord = new Scanner(System.in);
        int one = 1;
        int subtract = 4;
        do {
            System.out.print(question);
            user = userPassWord.next();
            if (user.equals(newPass)) {
                System.out.println("Pass Word is correct you may move on.");
                return true;
            } else {
                subtract = subtract - one;
                if(subtract >= 0) {
                    System.out.println("PassWord is wrong. You have " + subtract + " more trys.");
                }
            }
            if (subtract == 0) {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("You have no more trys left. Would you like to reset your PassWord?(Y/N)");
                    user = userPassWord.next();
                    if (user.equals("Y") || user.equals("y")) {
                        System.out.println("You May reset your Password.");
                        return passwordSetAndCheck();
                    } else if(user.equals("No") || user.equals("no")) {
                        return false;
                    } else  {
                        System.out.println("You need to answer the question.(Y/N)");
                    }
                }
            }
        } while(true);
    }


    public String setNewPassword() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String password;
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Please Enter your Pass word: ");
            password = scanner.next();
            if (password.length() >= 3) {
                System.out.println("This PassWord works.");
                return password;
            }
            System.out.println("This PassWord doesn't Work.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does making a seperate class only for display work? Or add different functions?

Comment: @Dav_DidHu  Of course, this code is poorly designed,  I just want to point out the cause of the problem. I'll edit my answers...

Comment: More like python-ish design.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. I put return in and it works just like I want it to work.

Comment: I am very new to java and I started my first class like 3 months ago and so I was just practicing and seeing what I could make.